# Missing destroy time for retained allocations

Tags: windows-phone-8, memory, memory-management, mvvm, memory-leaks

I've made a program In which I have one page, which has a button to another page, and the other page contains a lot of visual effects. Its possible to navigate back and forth between the two pages. However after navigating back to the first page (The one only containing a button) the memory increases with 20 mb. I've tried a lot of things and concluded that it is in the retained visuals where my problem lies.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As seen in the pictures, the only place where there is a significant change in memory is at the retained allocations, and when further inspecting these it is seen that there is no destroy time on them. I'm using the MVVM structure and tried to outcomment all the viewmodels and binding, both with no luck.

Is there a way to find out which elements that are hanging and what can be done to remove them once navigating back to the first page?